# How to write rules using RedirectMatch or RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have spent so much time to get the below thing working. But looks like it is not working.

I need to redirect users to:

```
/webcenter/portal/MyPortal
```

When they try to access:

```
/webcenter/ 
/webcenter/portal
/webcenter/portal/home
```

I tried with both `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule` in my configuration file of OHS server with out luck.

```
RewriteRule ^webcenter$ http://portal.abc.com/webcenter/portal/MyPortal [L]
```

Can you please help me here.

Comment: Do you have anything else on the `.htaccess` file or any other rules where you're placing the rules at? Are you placing the rules on the config file directly or on the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I already have this rule in place. RedirectMatch ^/$ http://portal.abc.com/webcenter/portal/MyPortal

Comment: I am placing the rules in custom config file under moduleconf folder in OHS home.

Comment: Hi @user2961454 , We have somewhat similar requirement , what i', doing is adding                                                                        RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com in httpd.conf file in <OHS-Instance>/ directory , but it doesn't do what I'm hoping . . May you please share your approach and entries that you made to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/webcenter/(portal|portal/home)?$ http://portal.abc.com/webcenter/portal/MyPortal [R=301,L]
```

Place it after the rule you already have.